# How to share files with multiple Android devices?

Tags: android, file, sharing

I want to build an app that's able to share it's data with itself on several different Android devices. Is there an easy implementation for that or do I need to use Dropbox or another cloud service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cloud service would be the most straightforward approach.

You could possibly share the files over LAN or BlueTooth, and synchronise them, but this would probably be more trouble than a cloud service, and harder to implement across the Internet.

[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) provides a developers API for such a purpose. This could be synced with each device.